# How to connect to a specific database with SQL Server in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I have the credentials to access the SQL Server database for the company I work. However, the user credentials it was provided to me only have the permission to access 1 specific database, called let's say: `database_name_1`

When I click in "List Databases" it says I have no permission to access the 'master' of the server and gives me an issue:  'QODBC3: Unable to connect'.
So, where could I specify it in QGIS for access only the `database_name_1`?

[image]

Comment: See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html. It should be possible to include the name of the database and even a list of tables into the connection string.